# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE : php excel export codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get an error when exporting my clients from my database. When using the code offline, it works, if I integrate it into my web application, I get an error.

The code is simple, I try to do an export to CSV file in a CodeIgniter application.

**error: This site is not accessible The web page at sitename.be/beheer/clients/export may have been temporarily disabled or permanently moved to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**

**controller:**

```
public function export(){

    // file name
    $filename = 'users_'.date('Ymd').'.csv';

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/csv; "); 

    // get data
    $usersData = $this->Client->getUserDetails();

    // file creation
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $header = array("reference","Name","client_id","phone","mobile","address","zipcode","city","inactive","website","country","vat","note","province","twitter","skype","linkedin","facebook","instagram","google","youtube","pinterest","terms");
    fputcsv($file, $header);

    foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){
     fputcsv($file,$line);
    }

    fclose($file);
    exit;
}
```

**Model:**

```
function getUserDetails(){

    $response = array();

    // Select record
    $this->db->select('*');
    $q = $this->db->get('companies');
    $response = $q->result_array();

    return $response;
}
```

**View**

blueline-> clients -> all this is the map where my view is

This is my code of my view

```
  < a href='<?= base_url() ?>clients/export' class="btn btn-primary">Export</a>
```

Comment: what's.... the error?

Comment: This site is not accessible
The web page at http://sitename.be/beheer/clients/export may have been temporarily disabled or permanently moved to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: You have a problem even before you get to your code I think. Do any of your pages work? Even a simple "die('test');" type thing?

Comment: Yes everything is working, my whole application is working but when i try to export i got this error. Even when i try to test it offline its working fine i got an export

Comment: $usersData = $this->Client->getUserDetails();
 try with 'c' instead of 'C' server is case sensitive

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy i tried it but its not working

Comment: start commenting out lines. Comment out all lines first, be sure that works, then uncomment one line at a time until it breaks, then you know which line causes the issue. Or you could just log errors, by modifying the error_log config variable in config.php

Comment: @MikeJouwstra Its kinda impossible cause there is i think a link error , when i push the link its not working

Comment: ic - thought it was working for you without this code.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the exact same problem!